# CustomTkinter - Unable to delete buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

edit 2: After testing, i've found that the display_menu method is still generating buttons after the last option is selected.
Is there a good way to ensure the buttons are only created if an option hasn't been selected?

New to Python, new to software development in general, please be nice :)
I am creating an app for the creation of usernames and passwords.
I have created a menu using nested dictionaries that store the menus and sub menus.
I have a method that creates buttons (two at a time, as this is the maximum number of options possible at one time) for the menus and sub menus.

Please note that this is really un-optimized and messy code, I am aware, i'm still working on these issues before I start working to make it neater.

Here is the method that defines the nested dictionaries:

```
class Menu:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.gui = GUI(master)
        self.memorable_password_instance = Memorable_Password_Class(self.gui)
        self.secure_password_instance = Secure_Password_class(self.gui)

        self.menu_options = {
            'main': {
                'title': 'Main Menu',
                'options': ['Generate a Username', 'Generate a Password'],
                'sub_menus': ['username_menu', 'password_menu'],
            },
            'password_menu': {
                'title': 'Password Generation',
                'options': ['Generate a Memorable Password', 'Generate a Secure Password'],
                'sub_menus': None,
                'functions': [self.memorable_password_instance.memorable_password_generator, self.secure_password_instance.secure_password_generator],
            },
            'username_menu': {
                'title': 'Username Generation',
                'options': ['Generate a Random Username', 'Generate a Personal Username'],
                'sub_menus': None
            }
        }


    def button_command(self, option, command_func):
        command_func(option)

    def display_menu(self, menu_key):
        menu = self.menu_options[menu_key]
        self.gui.create_label(menu['title'], row=0, column=1)

        if menu['sub_menus']:
            options_list = [sub_menu['title'] for sub_menu in [self.menu_options[sub_menu_key] for sub_menu_key in menu['sub_menus']]]
            command_func = lambda option: self.display_menu([sub_menu_key for sub_menu_key in self.menu_options if self.menu_options[sub_menu_key]['title'] == option][0])

        else:
            options_list = menu['options']
            command_func = lambda option: self.process_menu(menu_key, option)

        self.gui.create_menu_buttons(options_list, self.button_command, command_func)

    def process_menu(self, menu_key, option=None):
        if option:
            function_index = self.menu_options[menu_key]['options'].index(option)
            self.menu_options[menu_key]['functions'][function_index]()
        self.display_menu(menu_key)
```

Then there is three methods that create buttons and the title label for the currently selected menu key (dictionary) and generate the buttons by passing the callback commands and relevant text to display on the buttons.

When navigating the menu, the buttons should be created for the currently selected menu.
Once an option is pressed/button pressed, the new set of options/buttons are created and the old set are deleted. (I am aware that I could just update the buttons, but I found it easier to delete them and re-define them).
This does work properly for the first set of menu options, i.e if I click 'Generate a password' then those two buttons for the main menu are deleted, and the new buttons 'Generate a secure password, Generate a memorable password' are created. This is done by adding the buttons to a list when they are created and calling a 'delete_menu_items' method which deleted all of the items in the list.

When the user selects one of these buttons, the relevant class is called and the slider etc is created.
The 'delete_menu_items' (Same one used as before) is called before the slider is created, but the previous buttons are not deleted.

[The two buttons on top should not be visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm5ZH.png)

Strangely, if I press the 'confirm' button which you can see here, this does delete the buttons as I have also called the 'delete_menu_items' method in here.

I cannot see anything wrong with the syntax or the delete_menu_items and my gut tells me that the buttons are being recreated from the menu class (where the menu options are defined).

Edit: A quick update on the further troubleshooting I have done. I did suspect that maybe the 'delete items' method was not being correctly called. When adding 'print('word') to this method, the word is printed, which means it is being called correctly. I've tested adding a boolean value which flips once the user selects one of the options from the sub_menus, then adding a conditional while loop to prevent buttons from being created if they have been created already.

To me, this seems like an artefact is being left behind, but i'm absolutely stumped.

Comment: As the posted code is not a [mre], how can we reproduce the issue and identify the cause?

Comment: the program is quite long and since it is complex so i wanted to avoid pasting the entire program

Comment: We don't need the full code, just a *[strip down version of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)* that can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is with the display_menu method. When a sub-menu is selected, the command function that is created to handle button presses does not properly reference the sub-menu options. Instead of using self.menu_options to reference the sub-menu options, it is using the parent menu options. This causes the buttons to be recreated with the wrong options when a sub-menu is selected.

To fix this, the display_menu method should be updated to reference the sub-menu options correctly. Try this for the display_menu function

```
def display_menu(self, menu_key):
    menu = self.menu_options[menu_key]
    self.gui.create_label(menu['title'], row=0, column=1)

    if menu['sub_menus']:
        sub_menus = [self.menu_options[sub_menu_key] for sub_menu_key in menu['sub_menus']]
        options_list = [sub_menu['title'] for sub_menu in sub_menus]
        command_func = lambda option: self.display_menu([sub_menu_key for sub_menu_key in self.menu_options if self.menu_options[sub_menu_key]['title'] == option][0])

    else:
        options_list = menu['options']
        command_func = lambda option: self.process_menu(menu_key, option)

    self.gui.create_menu_buttons(options_list, self.button_command, command_func)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude, i've tried this solution but unfortunately it's the same result. Also, the buttons that are causing the issue aren't wrong, strictly speaking, but they should disappear after the memorable/secure password class is called. I have also tried adding a while loop that only continues if the 'sub_menus' menu key is not 'None' but this didn't fix the issue either. I'm now suspecting that this has something to do with the way Python is initializing the instance of the 'memorable password class' and is somehow still running the display_menu method in the background...

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue.

By adding a simple 'print('1')' to the menu creation logic, and 'print('2')' to the password creation logic, the console output was: 2, 1. This told me that the menu creator was instantly being called as the password class was not complete. I simply completed the password class, and added a back button which would pause the program until it was pressed.

Thanks for all of the help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).